# How to get the path to the EXE file of the program

Tags: c#

Please help how to get the path to the EXE file of the program.
The bottom line is that I need to open word files in the folder where is the EXE of my program. I run the word file through the Process.Start ("filename").

Comment: EXE file of your running program or other running programs?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for your requirement:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```